# Using a List within a dataset as tablix properties

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I have a fairly large output report to create with about 7 - 10 tables plus a ton of individual cells to populate.

Is it possible to use a List that is currently inside of a dataset as the tablix properties/dataset? Or would I need to create a new dataset for each table?

As a example of what I mean:

```
public class LibraryModel
{
 ....
 public List<BookModel> Books { get; set; }
 public List<AreaModel> Area { get; set; }
 ....
}

public class BookModel
{
 public string Author { get; set; }
 public string Isbn { get; set; }
 public double Price { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class AreaModel
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Genre { get; set; }
 public bool HasAdultContent { get; set; }
}
```

In this case would I be able to use *LibraryModel* as my only dataset in my report and use *BookModel* for one table and *AreaModel* for another table? And if so, how would I be able to do that?

Comment: Regardless, this question falls under the category of "try it and find out".

Comment: A tablix is a table in the report. It's what the reporting tool calls tables.

Comment: I am able to create the Lists easy enough and theoretically I think it should work (as it is a collection of information that the table can iterate through). The question is more can it be done this way, or to rephrase, would the software/tool allow this method to work. If not then multiple datasets it is; even though it makes the service file for the report a pain to create.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found was I can set up the model in this manner however each List item will not show the item as a field. Each list item has to be imported as a new dataset.

In the reporting service it will show as *LibraryModel (Books)* rather than using *BookModel* as the dataset.